# Shadow baking blurry in 3ds Max

Tags: 3dsmax

I am trying to bake shadows onto my floor texture, and these are the shadows I am trying to bake to the floor:

[image]

This is how the flattened floor texture looks like:

[image]

And this is how it looks when I apply it:

[image]

It doesn't look right in any way as the lines are off and it is very blurry.

I have tried several methods but with no luck. Any guiding would be highly appreciated!

Comment: this is incorrect to compare quality of the viewport Active shade, with quality of baked texture results. At least (but not only that) because two different render engines were used. Please render the camera with your actual light and shadow settings with (Vray|Corona|Whatever) render, and compare to baked texture variant. I expect them to be almost equal in quality. If not, pls update your post with new images.

Comment: What tools are you using for baking?  Are you using Render-to-Texture?  The results look like vertex colors rather than a texture bitmap, meaning they shadow detail is limited by the geometry resolution of the floor mesh.